# Shell: get lines x to y of file

Tags: shell, unix

What unix shell command can I use to get lines x (e.g. 10) to y (e.g. to 15) from a file. `grep` doesn't seem to help and except doing a for loop I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/06/print-range-of-lines-in-perl-based-upon.html

Comment: Yes! very much a duplicate, sorry! though KingsIndian solution can't be found there easily.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '5,10p' filename
```

to print lines from 5 to 10.

Answer (score 8):

head y, tail y-x

```
head -n 15 filename | tail -n 5
```

Comment: If x (e.g. 10) to y (e.g. to 15) is inclusive, then it must be 
`head -n 15 filename | tail -n 6 ` instead.

Answer (score 5):

awk:

```
awk 'NR>=10 and NR<=15' your_file
```

perl:

```
perl -lne 'print if($.>=10 && $.<=15)' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
> nawk 'NR>=10&&NR<=15' temp
10
11
12
13
14
15
> perl -lne 'print if($.>=10&&$.<=15)' temp
10
11
12
13
14
15
>
```

Comment: I like the awk solution very much, thanks! Too bad I never learned perl, look nice too.

Answer (score 4):

For bigger files :

```
sed '10,15! d;15q' file
```

Comment: Could you explain, please?

Comment: !d deletes all lines not between 10 to 15. 15q makes sed to quit processing at 15th line instead of processing till the last line.

Comment: It would still be helpful to learn what each bit of syntax does, it is not easy to understand even for an experienced person.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `head` and `tail`, e.g.

```
head -n 15 $file | tail -n 5
```